# Cartthrob Realex Direct/Global Iris transaction status not returned

Tags: cartthrob

I'm using the Realex Direct payment gateway (Global Iris), and the return page isn't showing the transaction's status (I'm using the docs' example code, hence the text showing beneath where the status should be):

[image]

I should note that previously I was instead getting a "The action you have requested is invalid" error returned. I solved that by adding "$config['secure_forms']; n" to the config file and/or setting csrf_exempt to = 1 in the database.

I gather the gateway uses 3D Secure / MPI. Could that be returning different results to what the plugin is expecting (maybe liability-related results?)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Cartthrob support solved my problem - thanks Chris!

In case it helps anyone in the future - I'd both submitted the wrong response URL to Realex, and failed to copy the language file to the relevant folder.